# I need to get number of employees per depatment

Tags: sql, select, count

This gets me the number of employees per department

```
SELECT department, COUNT(idEmployees) empCount
FROM employees
GROUP BY department;
```

Comment: Please tag appropriately.  Which RDBMS are you using, MySQL or SQL Server?  They are not the same.  I removed the tags, please edit your question to add the correct tag back.

Answer (score 1):

You could join on `departments` to get the `buildingID`, and then group by that:

```sql
SELECT   buildingID, COUNT(*)
FROM     employees e
JOIN     department d ON e.department = d.departmentID
GROUP BY buildingID
```

Answer (score 1):

i think this is the solution

```
select d.buildingID, count(e.ID)
from department d
inner join employees e  
on d.departmentID = e.department
group by d.buildingID
```

Answer (score 1):

This question can be answered in **two ways**. Firstly, if **all** employees of a department must be attached in a building. Secondly **few** employees of a department are attached to a building.

For one where employees are attached to a building it's **mandatory**

```
SELECT d.buildingId
     , COUNT(e.id) count_employee
FROM departments d
INNER JOIN employees e
        ON d.departmentid = e.department
GROUP BY d.buildingId
```

For second where employees are attached to a building but it's **optional**. In that case LEFT JOIN is used.

```
SELECT b.buildingId
     , COALESCE(t.count_employee, 0) count_employee
FROM building b
LEFT JOIN (SELECT d.buildingId
                , COUNT(e.id) count_employee
           FROM departments d
           INNER JOIN employees e
                   ON d.departmentid = e.department
           GROUP BY d.buildingId) t
       ON b.buildingId = t.buildingId
```

If a building is attached with **multiple departments** and one employee is assigned with multiple departments then count building wise same employee is **only** onetime not multiple times. In that case **DISTINCT** keyword is used inside **COUNT()**.

```
SELECT d.buildingId
     , COUNT(DISTINCT e.id) count_employee
FROM departments d
INNER JOIN employees e
        ON d.departmentid = e.department
GROUP BY d.buildingId
```